# ng-repeat filter not exact match from drop down selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table that lists TV shows and I have drop down menu to allow an optional filter. The result of that drop down selection filters the list.However, I have come across a problem where it doesn't filter the specific show.

There are two shows that are similar in my list:
Fear the Walking Dead
The Walking Dead

If I was to filter and select "The Walking Dead" from the drop down selection. It shows both shows as the result.

```
<tr id='tv_schedule_row' ng-repeat='tv_show in tv_shows | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:filterText | itemsPerPage:20'>#
```

I've tried adding `:true` after `filterText` but it just means when the page is loaded, the list is not displayed since a filter has not been selected but it should display all the results without a filter.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<tr id='tv_schedule_row' ng-repeat='tv_show in tv_shows | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:(filterText || undefined):true | itemsPerPage:20'>
```